# How to get unique username, email id? And how to get radio button value (Male or Female) in database.

Tags: java, android

Please help me as I'm beginner in android..In this I can register more than one time using same username and email id so how to get unique username and email id.
Also how to add radio button value (Male or Female) into the database. Can I select multiple values from spinner and display into database.. Thanks in advance.

Here is Register.java file.

```
package com.example.login;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

EditText fname, lname, emailid, username, pass, cpass;
RadioGroup selection;
RadioButton male, female;
Spinner usrtyp, hobbies;
TextView type, hoby;
Button submit;
ContentValues values;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("login", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (ID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, F_NAME VARCHAR(200), L_NAME VARCHAR(200), EMAIL_ID VARCHAR(20), GENDER VARCHAR(20), USERNAME VARCHAR(200), PASSWORD VARCHAR(16), C_PASSWORD VARCHAR(16), HOBBIES VARCHAR(200), USER_TYPE VARCHAR(200));");

    values = new ContentValues();

    fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    emailid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailid);
    selection = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male);
    female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    cpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cpassword);
    hoby = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvhobbies);
    hobbies = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usertype);
    usrtyp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);



    // Hobbies
    hobbies.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    List<String> hoby = new ArrayList<String>();
    hoby.add("Sports");
    hoby.add("Movies");
    hoby.add("Travelling");
    hoby.add("Reading");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            hoby);
    dataadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    hobbies.setAdapter(dataadapter);

    // User Type
    usrtyp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    List<String> user = new ArrayList<String>();
    user.add("Admin");
    user.add("Normal User");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataadapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            user);
    dataadapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    usrtyp.setAdapter(dataadapter1);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                String firstName = fname.getText().toString();
                String lastName = lname.getText().toString();
                String Email_ID = emailid.getText().toString();
                String Gender = male.getText().toString();
                String userName = username.getText().toString();
                String Password = pass.getText().toString();
                String confirmPassword = cpass.getText().toString();
                String Hobbies = hobbies.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String userType = usrtyp.getSelectedItem().toString();


                //Check vacant
                if (firstName.equals("") || lastName.equals("") || Email_ID.equals("") || userName.equals("")
                        || Password.equals("") || confirmPassword.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill Vacant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                //check if password doesn't match
                if (!Password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password doesn't match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } 
                else

                values.put("F_NAME", firstName);
                values.put("L_NAME", lastName);
                values.put("EMAIL_ID", Email_ID);
                values.put("USERNAME", userName);
                values.put("PASSWORD", Password);
                values.put("GENDER", Gender);
                values.put("C_PASSWORD", confirmPassword);
                values.put("HOBBIES", Hobbies);
                values.put("USER_TYPE", userType);

                db.insert("USERS", null, values);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully submited", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Login.java file..

```
package com.example.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText uname, pass;
Button login;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signin);

    uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginusername);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginpassword);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("login", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    login.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        String user_Name = uname.getText().toString();
        String Password1 = pass.getText().toString();

        // If username or password is not entered
        if (user_Name.equals("") || Password1.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Username and      Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        } else {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE userName = '" + user_Name + "' AND Password = '" + Password1
                    + "'";

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                i.putExtra("un", user_Name);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

}
```

Home.java file.

```
package com.example.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home extends Activity {

TextView tv1;
ListView lv;
String un;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("login", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Intent ii = getIntent();
    Bundle b = ii.getExtras();

    String temp = (String) b.get("un");
    tv1.setText("Welcome " + temp);


    int c=0;

    try {

        String query1 = "SELECT * FROM USERS;";
        Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(query1, null);
        if(c1.moveToFirst()){
            String[] temp2 = new String[c1.getCount()];
            do{
                String tempo =c1.getString(0) + " " + c1.getString(1) + " " + c1.getString(2) + " " + c1.getString(4) + " " + c1.getString(8) + " " + c1.getString(9);


                temp2[c]=tempo;
                c++;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c1.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            while(c1.moveToNext());

            ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temp2);
            lv.setAdapter(adp);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: radio button value (Male or Female) = boolean field. For unique value for pair (user,email) you need another key to distinguish.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how to set radio button in sqlite database.

Comment: If you have only 2 values, you can use on boolean field, 0=male and 1=female for example.

Comment: ok but what and where to write? Please explain in brief because I'm not much experienced in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing this I got unique Email ID:

```
String id = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Email_ID = '" + Email_ID + "'";
                Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery(id, null);
                if (c2.getCount() > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ID already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
```

Same for the Username.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an unique ID in your tables provided by SQLite, try:

```
select rowid,* from USERS
```

The first column will be the auto generated ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (ID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 F_NAME VARCHAR(200), 
L_NAME VARCHAR(200), 
EMAIL_ID VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
 GENDER VARCHAR(20),
 USERNAME VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE, 
PASSWORD VARCHAR(16), 
C_PASSWORD VARCHAR(16),
 HOBBIES VARCHAR(200), 
USER_TYPE VARCHAR(200));");
```

Now you can't have repeating username and e mailid.
I suggest using char in gender column use 1 or 0.
and i don't know you meant saying that display into database

Comment: Still i can register with same username and Email id. @burak Karasoy

Comment: And look at my code. I'm not getting female value of radio button as a string. String Gender = male.getText().toString(); By this I'm getting male value.. What to do if I want male or female (which is selected) as a string..

Comment: try not null unique instead of using just unique also read this paragraph it seems helpful for you https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q26.